# XML to csv(-like) format

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have an XML file, which I would like to convert / export to a csv(-like) format.

Example:

```
<root>
  <child>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Surname>Doe</Surname>
    <Name>George</Name>
    <Surname>Washington</Surname>
  </child>
</root>
```

ATM I do it like this (the print is for debug, nothing finished yet):

```
#!/bin/python env

import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

tree = etree.parse('./foobar.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

elements = ('Name', 'Surname')

for i in elements:
  for i in root.iter(i):
    print(i.text)
```

**Current Output:**

```
John
George
Doe
Washington
```

**The result I would like to get:**

```
John, Doe
George, Washington
```

Can anyone give me a hand here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: do you mean to have a comma between "Doe" and "Goerge"?

Answer (score 6):

Use xpath and zip().

```
#!python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

root = etree.parse('./foobar.xml').getroot()

for a in zip(root.findall("child/Name"), root.findall("child/Surname")):
    print(", ".join([x.text for x in a]))
```

If you want to call flexible with names of elements.

```
#!python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

child = etree.parse('./foobar.xml').getroot().find('child')

elements = ('Name', 'Surname')

for a in zip(*[child.findall(x) for x in elements]):
  print(", ".join([x.text for x in a]))
```

Comment: When I write to csv it appends all in one row.  Example:                               csv.write(",\n ".join([x.text for x in a]))