# Targeting specific sub-elements when parsing XML with Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm working on building a simple parser to handle a regular data feed at work. This post, [XML to csv(-like) format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580246/xml-to-csv-like-format) , has been very helpful.  I'm using a for loop like in the solution, to loop through all of the elements/subelements I need to target but I'm still a bit stuck.

For instance, my xml file is structured like so:

```
<root>
  <product>
    <identifier>12</identifier>
    <identifier>ab</identifier>
    <contributor>Alex</contributor>
    <contributor>Steve</contributor>
  </product>
<root>
```

I want to target only the second identifier, and only the first contributor. Any suggestions on how might I do that?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer you pointed to has an example of how to turn all instances of a tag into a list.  You could just loop through those and discard the ones you're not interested in.

However, there's a way to do this directly with XPath: the mini-language supports item indexes in brackets:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
document = etree.parse(open("your.xml"))

secondIdentifier = document.find(".//product/identifier[2]")
firstContributor = document.find(".//product/contributor[1]")
print secondIdentifier, firstContributor
```

prints

```
'ab', 'Alex'
```

Note that in XPath, the first index is `1`, not `0`.

ElementTree's `find` and `findall` only support a subset of XPath, described [here](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm).  Full XPath, described in brief on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) and more fully in the [W3C's normative document](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is available from [lxml](http://lxml.de/), a third-party package, but one that is widely available.  With lxml, the example would look like this:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
document = etree.parse(open("your.xml"))

secondIdentifier = document.xpath(".//product/identifier[2]")[0]
firstContributor = document.xpath(".//product/contributor[1]")[0]
print secondIdentifier, firstContributor
```

Comment: Great, thank you Jim. I think your examples are exactly what I need. To your first point, most of the products have different quantities of each element, so I end up with lists of varying lengths, making it harder to systematically target the elements I need.